# how to use a soap datasource with mysql

Tags: cakephp, datasource, cakephp-2.0

I've created a `DataSource` for connecting to a `WSDL` server and post/get data.

But, I don't know how to use it in a controller? with a MySQL database (I mean I need both of them, a `soap` and a database is needed.)

If I put this in my model, it will use my datasource; but I think it won't use its mysql table...:

```
public $useTable = false;
public $useDbConfig = 'mydatasource';
```

How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $this->Modelname->setDataSource('default') and setDataSource('mydatasource') to switch between the two sources on the fly.

But you also need to change between using a table, and not using a table, i use the following code to switch between a no-table source, and mysql:

```
public $oldSource = array();

public function setDbConfig($source = null, $useTable = null) {
    $ds = $this->getDataSource();
    if (method_exists($ds, 'flushMethodCache')) {
        $ds->flushMethodCache();
    }
    if ($source) {
        $this->oldSource = array('useTable' => $this->useTable, 'useDbConfig' => $this->useDbConfig);
        $this->setDataSource($source);
        if ($useTable !== null) {
            $this->setSource($useTable);
        }
    } else {
        if ($this->oldSource) {
            $this->setDataSource($this->oldSource['useDbConfig']);
            $this->setSource($this->oldSource['useTable']);
            $this->oldSource = array();
        }
    }
}
```